# Read data from LIS2DE12 accelerometer

Tags: linux, usb, devices, output, i2c

I am trying to read the acceleration data in the X, Y and Z axes from the [LIS2DE12](http://dev.gateworks.com/datasheets/lis2de12.pdf) accelerometer which is connected to an I2C-to-USB adapter, it is [UMFT201XB](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Modules/DS_UMFT201_220_230XB.pdf).

I am using a virtual machine in VirtualBox whose operating system is a lubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. I was planning to read it directly from the linux terminal without using any kind of C program as I found on this [website](http://trac.gateworks.com/wiki/accelerometer) but /sys/bus/iio... directories do not exist for me. I have also read in other posts like [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/346123/reading-data-from-umft200xd-or-umft201xb) where the user @Ashutosh said that the UMFT201XB adapter has the [FT201X](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT201X.pdf) chipset so it only has I2C slave functionality and since the accelerometer is another slave, you can't initialize the communication.

In VirtualBox, the USB device is being detected as when I run the `dmesg` I get the following output:

```
$ dmesg

usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ohci-pci
usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6015, bcdDevice=10.00
usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-1: Product: UMFT201XB
usb 1-1: Manufacturer: FTDI
usb 1-1: SerialNumber: FT5BIUOL
ftdi_sio 1-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
usb 1-1: Detected FT-X
usb 1-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

This way I know it's in located in `/dev/ttyUSB0` but I've been trying tools like screen or stty but I don't get any results. Neither when using cat or tail to read the output.

**EDIT 1**

After some research i found this entrance on [FT201X](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT201X.pdf) datasheet:

> Please note that the FT200XD and FT201X are I2C slave devices only and
> should be interfaced to an I2C host (often in a microcontroller or
> FPGA). If an I2C master is required, please see the FT232H, FT2232H,
> FT4232H and FT2232D devices.

So I decided to look for devices with those chipsets. They all have MPSSE interface so I don't really know where the SDA and SCL pins are but, I managed to find a picture of [UM232H](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/DS_UM232H.pdf) device which indicated where these pins are, SDA being a short between AD1 and AD2 and, SCL being the AD0 pin. So, my question now is a bit different... before I buy anything is this device good for the application I want to do?